# How is Devise changing my subdomain in my mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have the following email that gets sent via Devise after I create a new admin.

```
<p>Welcome <%= @email %>!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', "http://admin.myapp.com/devise_admin/admins/confirmation?confirmation_token=#{@token}" %></p>
```

The issue I'm having is that even though I explicitly list `http://admin.myapp.com...` as my subdomain. In the actual email, the link takes me to `http://www.myapp.com...`

How is devise overwriting my subdomain when I've hardcoded it? Is it perhaps not using this view to generate the email?

Comment: I was able to figure this out. The view was not being overriding devise's view because it was not in the same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `host` configuration in the devise initializer

Actually its in the environments/[ENVIRONMENT] files

`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: "localhost",port: 3000}`